# Jquery function doesn't get parameter

Tags: jquery, function

I'm using this function:

```
    $(function echo_content(name, content) {
        var random1 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*500);
        var random2 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000);
        alert(content);
        $('#TheDiv').show("slow");
});
```

And i'm calling this function on my webpage like this:

```
    <td>Content <script>echo_content("MyName", "The Content"); </script></td>
```

The problem is, that the function alerts `undefined` instead of `The Content`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a JQuery DOM ready handler. Just define your function like that:

```
function echo_content(name, content) {
    var random1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 500);
    var random2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000);
    alert(content);
    $("#TheDiv").show("slow");
}
```

BTW, `#TheDiv` block should be loaded before you call the function.

Comment: Your suggestion does not work. It doesn't show the alert. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you please tell me why this doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/DSgeb/2/ ?
My echo_content function is in scripts.js which is included into website.
Thanks! :)

Comment: @JernejPangeršič This doesn't work because your `echo_content` function is not defined in the scope. JSFiddle places the JS block to DOM ready handler. Use my example to get it work in JSFiddle. Check your `scripts.js` is included *before* you call the function.

Comment: How silly of me, I had scripts.js included afterwards :)
Thank you very much! :)